# How to merge two methods in one (.style + .getcomputed style)

Tags: javascript, selenium, ide

I have some form. I need to check backgroundColor of ALL elements in this form. But in some elements colors are defined by `<style>`, and another elemenets colors are defined by css. I need to merge two methods in one (in Selenium IDE)

Here is my methods:

1(.style):

```
var form = window.document.forms[0]; 
elements = form.elements; 
for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    color = elements[i].style.backgroundColor;
}
```

2(.getcomputedstyle):

```
var form = window.document.forms[0]; 
elements = form.elements; 
for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
var color = window.document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elements[i])
        .getPropertyValue('background-color');
var colorArr = color.replace(/[\\rrgb\\(\\)]/g, '').split(','); 
var hexString = '#'
        + parseInt(colorArr[0]).toString(16)
        + parseInt(colorArr[1]).toString(16)
        + parseInt(colorArr[2]).toString(16);
}
```

Comment: P.S. I need to convert color in rrggbb (HEX)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second method is getting the colors that are actually being displayed in the browser (they may come from inline styles, or internal and/or external css), so you don't need the first one at all (that colors may have been overridden). And the second method is already converting rgb values to hex (do you maybe need it the other way around?)

Comment: If you want your script to work in IE8-, you might want to use [this script described here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html).